# How to get the returned value from Ajax Request and assigned it into an element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need a little help here. I am creating a dynamic dropdown list but I don't know how to display the ajax result in an element.

Here's my scenario:

- The user will choose a state in the dropdown.
- After choosing the code will send an ajax request
- After sending, display the result in a select option named 'cities'

So there are 2 select box. One is 'state' and second is 'cities'.
Here's my code:

Here's my jquery for accessing the controller

```
$('#state').on('change',function(){

    var state_code = $('#state').val();

    var city_url = '<?php echo site_url("locations/displayCity/' + state_code + '"); ?>';

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: city_url,
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(){
            //
        }

    });

});
```

Here's my function in the model

```
public function getCity($code){

    $sql = "SELECT id,name FROM ref_cities WHERE province_code = '".$code."'";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);

    return json_encode($result->result_array());

}
```

Here's the controller part

```
public function displayCity($code){

    $x = json_decode($this->locations_model->getCity($code));

    return print_r($x);

}
```

Here's the code in my selecting the city code

```
<select id="state" name="state">
    <option value="">---Select State---</option>
    <?php

        $decode_city = json_decode($city,true);

        foreach($decode_city as $m){
            echo "<option value='".$m['code']."' ".set_select('state',$m['code']).">".$m['name']."</option>";
        }

    ?>
</select>
```

Here's the part where should I put the ajax result

```
<select id="city" name="city">
    <option value="">---Select City---</option>
    <!-- INCLUDE LOOP TO DISPLAY cities -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
jQuery.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: city_url,
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            //you will get the result in data
           //jQuery("#someDiv").html(data);
           //The parsed data is something like below
           jQuery.each(jQuery.parseJSON(data), function(key,value){
           jQuery("#city").append('<option value ="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
           });
        }


    });
```

Hope its get fixed.

Comment: I set it. Same as the ID in my city. By the way the #someDiv is the initial dropdown or the second dropdown?

Comment: just alert the data and parse that in correct format and append to the city

Comment: Hello sorry for the late reply. When i alert the data. It doesn't alerting. And There's no response also.

Comment: can you just fn_print_die(x) print this content ?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
    $('#state').on('change',function(){

            var state_code = $('#state').val();

            var city_url = 'controller_file.php?state_code=<?php echo state_code; ?>';

            $.ajax({

                type: 'GET',
                url: city_url,
                data: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                 var response_arr = JSON.parse(response);

                   $.each(response_arr ,function(index,value)
                   {
                    $("#city").append("<option value="+value.id+">"+value.name+"</option>");
});
                }

            });

        });
```

in controller_file.php file write this

```
displayCity($_GET['state_code']);
```

Comment: Wait! I forgot that you used json_encoded response. I made a small change, now it will do.. Sorry about the before response. :/

Comment: Sir If I include a parameter (response) in the function. It doesn't display the ajax results.

Comment: I can't get the reponse in the function. There's no response. I alert also but it failed.

Comment: In the controller, do you call for "displayCity($code)" method? And also I don't know about "fn_print_die", just try using echo $x instead of that

Comment: sorry the fn_print_die() is for displaying the array in print_r()

Comment: Where do you call for displayCity($code) mthod inside your comtroller?

Comment: Yes it is in my controller

Comment: What I meant was, you need to invoke that method some where in your code right? Where do you do that?

Comment: It is in the city_url = '<?php echo site_url("locations/displayCity/' + state_code + '"); ?>';

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#state').on('change',function(){
var cityList = '';
    var state_code = $('#state').val();

    var city_url = '<?php echo site_url("locations/displayCity/' + state_code + '"); ?>';

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: city_url,
        data: '',
        dataType: 'String',
        success: function(data){

                  $('#city').html(data);
        }

    });

});
```

you can rewrite your code like this. it will work

or you can try this

```
public function getCity($code){

    $sql = "SELECT id,name FROM ref_cities WHERE province_code = '".$code."'";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $cities = $result->result_array();
    $options = '';
    foreach($cities as $city){
    $options .= '<option value="'.$city["id"].'">'.$city["name"].'</option>';
    }
    return $options;

}
```

this should work try this

Comment: Ok I tried that too. But it is not working. If I include a parameter in 'data' in the function. It doesn't display the ajax results.

Comment: in "data" array you will get your values. now check in which form your data.

Comment: can you use console your data value "console.log(data)"

Comment: I used the developer tools in chrome. But if I include the data as my parameter. It doesn't display the reponse

Comment: cityList += '<option value ='+data[key].id+'>'+data[key].name+'</option>'; try this

Comment: yeah now i have made some changes from your php code. i hope this should work

Comment: have you changed the dataType: 'String'?

Comment: Yes. But same effect. :(

Comment: cityList += '<option value ='+data.key.id+'>'+data.key.name+'</option>'; last your try this your code

Comment: Ok I will try that too.

Comment: have you checked you get the correct json data from your controller?

Comment: It return the value if I include the print_r but if I simple return json_decode(); It doesn't

Comment: in chrome Inspect Element->Network you check your request and see what result you get

Comment: the data should be in json format so tht only you can process

Comment: Ok I solved my problem in displaying the response in console.

Comment: What I did is simple remove the json_decode in the controller and echo.

Answer (score 1):

your success function must be something like this

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(key,value){
    $('<option/>','{value:'+value+'}').appendTo('#yourparent');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to answer my question. Here's what I did

In my Controller I removed the json_decode(). And now I have this

```
public function displayCity($code){
    $x = $this->locations_model->getCity($code);
    echo $x;
}
```

Then I can access it in console.

```
$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: city_url,
    data: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(i){
       console.log(i);
    }

});
```

Comment: Nut my other problem is how can I append the values in the select box options?